# GDB shows the wrong thread in postmortem analysis

Tags: linux, multithreading, gdb, core-file

I am experiencing a strange behavior of GDB. When running a post-mortem analysis of a core, dumped from a heavily multithreaded application in c++, the debugger commands

```
bt
where
thread info
```

never tell me the thread which the program actually crashed. It keeps showing me the thread number 1. As I am used to see this working from other Systems, I am curious if is is a Bug in GDB or if they changed the behavior somehow. Can anyone point me to a solution of this, it is PITA to search through 75 Threads, just to find out something the Debugger already knows.

By the way, I am on Debian Squeeze (6.0.1), the version of GDB is 7.0.1-debian, the System is x86 and completely 32-Bit. On my older Debian (5.x) installation, debugging a core, dumped by the exact same source, delivers me a backtrace of the correct thread, as does GDB on a Ubuntu 10.04 installation.

Thanks!

Comment: When GDB initializes and reads the core file, it doesn't give the summary of termination?  Usually that includes the active thread summary.

Comment: After booting it up today, I recompiled my source and let it crash again. GDB now works like a charm. Now I am even more confused... but thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 5):

GDB does not know which thread caused the crash, and simply shows the first thread that it sees in the `core`.

The Linux kernel usually dumps the faulting thread first, and that is why on most systems you end up in exactly the correct thread once you load `core` into GDB.

I've never seen a kernel where this was broken, but I've never used Debian 6 either.

My guess would be that this was broken, and then got fixed, and Debian 6 shipped with a broken kernel.

You could try upgrading the kernel on your Debian 6 machine to match e.g. your Ubuntu 10.04, and see if the problem disappears.

Alternatively, Google user-space [coredumper](http://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper/) does it correctly. You can link it in, and call it from SIGSEGV handler.

Comment: It's working again. Still don't understand what was messed up. Anyway, your answer is enlightening and the Google user-space coredumper seems worth a closer look. Thanks.